# What HTML5 markup for grouping headings in a table?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, semantic-markup

I have a table where the data rows are grouped into categories.

Currently I've styled them like this:

[image: Table of 4 columns with 2 groups of rows. Each group has an extra row with a bold label/heading.]

Currently those two group headers ("Baseline" and "Performer") are simply an extra `<TR>` with a col-spanning `<TD>`. This makes me feel dirty.

I want to get rid of that `<thead>` at the very top, and incorporate the headings into each group header. I understand I can't have multiple `<thead>` elements in a table, and there is no such thing as a `<tgroup>`.

I don't want to break the table into multiple tables as there are different ways of sorting the complete set of data (e.g. the table could be grouped by Category instead).

What markup should I use to:

1. hide/dispose/delete the top-most table header
2. insert the relevant headings into each group heading
3. still be accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make Feature Group/Type a column next to the Category column, instead of breaking the rows into sections.

*edited to add*

In that case I'd make the col-spanning row a th instead of a td. Give it an id attribute like id="baseline", and give an id to the column header as well. Then for the content rows, give the first cell a headers attribute which refers to those ids. This is valid, but the support for headers/id association in screenreaders is a bit inconsistent so you might have to do a bit of testing and tweak it to get a decent result. Usually scope=row/col is sufficient, but headers/id is intended for multiple headers like you have.

If your first cell is a th, give it a scope="row" just to distinguish it from the other th elements. e.g.

```
<thead>
  <tr><th id="feature">Feature</th><th>Category</th><th>B</th><th>P</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><th id="baseline" col-span="4">Baseline</th></tr>
  <tr><th scope="row" headers="baseline feature">Account activity</th><td>Accounts</td><td>59%</td><td>34%</td></tr>
 ...
</tbody>
```

You can see a more detailed explanation here: http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data

Comment: Unfortunately, the grouping is an important thing, more important than being a simple data-cell for each row.

Comment: Oh in that case you can go to a more complex method, associating cells using id/headers attributes. But this comment won't let me put markup in, so I'll edit my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not want to split them into multiple tables, however in IMHO that would make this kind of structure very accessible. You can have all the group heading at same `aria-level`, then inside each group you can have a proper table with column headers. 
To provide options of search, sort etc you would need to have a an action bar with proper descriptions of each action at same or lower `aria-level`. You can also make each group a list item in a container (from perspective of accessibility tools).